# Use sklearn or existing module to cluster text let each cluster belongs to multilabel

Tags: text, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn, text-classification

I have data like this

```
  [
  'The actor in New York. The art of Static.',
  'The actor in New York. Sword.',
  'The actor in New York. Handsome Jonny Deep.',
  'France, the greast tower. In Las Vegas, the great hotel.',
  'Empire State Building. This night is great!',
  'Empire State Building wow! This night is so so so so great!',
  'The light of life. Make you think of the future ans the love.',
  'The light of street. Make you consider that where is my road tomorrow?',
  'A scrolled cat palying on the ground. cute',
  'A surprised woman in a dark raining day.',
  'The sunshine makes the cat wants to sleep.',
  'Three in one image that a cat is smelling the flower.',
  'A woman with smile is looking at the falling leaves.',
  'A headshot of a fat squirrel.',
  'A headshot of a yellow cat.',
  'A cat runs on the snow and jumps very high.',
  'A dog grovals on the falling leaves and looks at camera.',
  'One cat stares at the camera, another is looking around.',
  'A dog with long tongue plays on the grass.'
  'A sad dog wants to see the world outside the house.'
  ]
```

I want to cluster them and label each of them with more than one label. Is that possible to use existing tool? I don't have enough time to implement by myself. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You need to provide more detail on what you mean by cluster. That has a pretty ambiguous meaning. Can you provide example output?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at gensim: http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/

Comment: What do you need the clusters for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **gensim** : http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/

You can use LDA, a method that can give you a distribution of tags (topics) for each one of your documents (phrases). Then you can use a method to cluster them based on the distributions of topics - like a K-Means, for example, that would work.

Please take a look: http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html

And then you use the K-Means method from sklearn.